# A more parsimonious way of reading in a series of CSVs?

Tags: r

Let's say I'm writing an R script that's pulling data from Quandl (or a series of .csv's, or any other type of sequential repeated command)

```
St_AL <- Quandl("datalocation/_ST_AL")
St_AK <- Quandl("datalocation/_ST_AK")
St_AZ <- Quandl("datalocation/_ST_AZ")
St_AR <- Quandl("datalocation/_ST_AR")
St_CA <- Quandl("FRBC/EMPL_ST_CA")
##SEQUENCE CONTINUES FOR ALL 50 U.S. STATES, or any other sequence##
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this that doesn't take 50 lines of code? I was thinking, maybe a string that has the 50 state names as values and then substituting string values into a loop? But I couldn't think of a way to implement it. Is that the key? or something else?

Answer (score 5):

As @PierreLafortune said you can use `state.abb` as list of states, with the `lapply()` function to loop over each of them:

```
lapply(state.abb, FUN=function(x) Quandl(paste0("datalocation/_ST_",x)))
```

or as @RichardScriven advised:

```
lapply(paste0("datalocation/_ST_",state.abb), Quandl)
```

You can arrange all the results into a single `data.frame` with:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0("datalocation/_ST_",state.abb), Quandl))
```

Comment: You can use the built-in vector of 50 state abbreviations `state.abb`

Comment: Or `lapply(sprintf("datalocation/_ST_", state.abb), Quandl)`.  Also `paste()` would go well in the first arg too because it's vectorized.  As is, your code pastes on every iteration when it doesn't have to.  Good answer though.

Comment: Thank you @HubertL (and others too!) that is amazing. I am always amazed and how wonderful people are on Stack Overflow. Thumbs up for Team Humanity.